# Manage objects even nonexistent "add listener object AS3 Which does not exist"

Tags: actionscript-3

how to add event listener in object not exist?

example i have 3 movieclps inside 3 buttons in one movieclip and in other 2 buttons.

i have one CLASS BASE to add the same functionaliti like this:

```
   btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionBtn1);
   btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionBtn1);
   btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionBtn1);
```

but one movie clip has onli 1 button and i got error i try to solve like this is ok?

```
    try{
    btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionBtn1);
    btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionBtn1);
    btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionBtn1);
    }catch(e:Error){
    trace("this is not error?");
    }
enter code here
```

you know how to solve this problems to manage objects already not exists?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply check if your object actually exists:

```
if(btn1)
    btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionBtn1);
if(btn2)
    btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionBtn1);
if(btn3)
    btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionBtn1);
```

This expressions checks if any of your buttons are *null* and skips one if it doesn't exist